# splitting pdf with pdftk

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf document with an even number of pages, say 2n, and I would like to split it into n documents, say pages1_2.pdf, pages3_4.pdf, ....., pages2n-1_2n.pdf, each of which consists of 2 successive pages. More precisely, for any i in the interval {1..2n}, the i-th file should consist of page 2i-1 and page 2i of the original document.

pdftk does not seem to have a dedicated function but I think that with a for loop this could be achieved.

Could you please help me in writing the right script? Thank you in advance

Comment: What is `pdftk`, it doesn't seem to be part of macOS?

Comment: pdftk is a command-line software that can manipulate PDF files. You can download it from the official pdftk web page https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an app called [PDFsam](https://pdfsam.org). SAM stands for split and merge. There is a free Basic version of this app and you can set the pages to keep together. You can split every n pages.  It should do what you want without coding.